# WPF Color animation binding TO to SolidColorBrush.Color

Tags: wpf, animation, colors

I am trying to bind a ColorAnimation TO={Binding Source={StaticResource Test1}, Path=Color}

I am able to do this with a SolidColorBrush but I get a 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'  exception when trying to use it in the color animation.

Here's What I Have:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Test1" Color="{Binding Source={x:Static self:MySettings.Default}, Path=HighlightColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Test2" Color="{Binding Source={x:Static self:MySettings.Default}, Path=TextColor}"/>

<Style x:Key="WindowLabel" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource HighlightBorder}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Test2}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="{Binding Source={StaticResource Test1}, Path=Color}" 
                                    Duration="{StaticResource AnimSpeed}" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="{Binding Source={StaticResource Test2}, Path=Color}" 
                                    Duration="{StaticResource AnimSpeed}" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The Test2 SolidColorBrush works fine, so why doesn't the animation?

Comment: I have just tried changing the To="Red" and it works fine, so it must be the binding, but why?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not how you bind but that you bind. If you would go into inner exception you would see this error:

> Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads.

Which basically means that because `Storyboards` use threads they, and everything they use, need to freezable and `Bindings` aren't. `Storyboard` cannot use dynamic value which might change during animation.

You can try to replace `SolidColorBrush` with `Color`, like below, but you also may need to do something with `Duration`

```
<Color  A="255" R="100" G="0" B="0" x:Key="Test1"/>
<Color A="255" R="0" G="100" B="0" x:Key="Test2"/>
...
<Style TargetType="Border">
  <Setter Property="Background">
      <Setter.Value>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Test2}"/>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation To="{StaticResource Test1}"
                  Duration="0:0:1" 
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation To="{StaticResource Test2}" 
                  Duration="0:0:1" 
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: That works fine, but what I am trying to do is dynamically change the colors. With your solution I am still using a static resource. Can I bind the R, G, B to anything?

Comment: Do you change your color/brush after loading from settings?